# conectar proyecto local a base de datos godaddy

Tags: mysql, sql, godaddy

Alguien sabe como obtener mi hostname de mi base de datos en godaddy?
Lei en la información que da y ponen LOCALHOST, pero mi proyecto aun lo estoy modificando localmente.
Quisiera poder conectar a la base de mi servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo logre, es la dirección de HOSTNAME es "IPDeMySQL".host.secureserver.net
Y que en MySQL remoto este en comodín o la IP de donde trabajaran